# Similar package to tikzscale for pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, tikzscale, pst-optexp

For integrating figures drawn in tikz in my projects I use `tikzscale` such that I do not have to worry about font scaling (and can simply use `\includegraphics{}` for including figures. I also use `pdflatex` for compiling, together with `--shell-escape`.
Is there a similar package/other trick for doing the same thing when including figures drawn using pstricks, especially when using pst-optexp? Then I would have to spend less time for rescaling font sizes such that the font in my figure aligns in size with the font I use in my document.

Comment: In general, you don't need any package:  you may change the unit length with `\psset{unit= some length.}` at the beginning of the `pspicture` environment. You also may change the font size locally. Note you can change the units on each axis independently with `\psset{xunit=…, yunit=…}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-0.3)(3,3.3)
  \pnode(0,2.5){A}\pnode(2,2.5){B}\pnode(2,1.5){C}
  \mirror[labelangle=-45](A)(B)(C){M}
  \optbox[position=start, labeloffset=0, labelref=relative](C)(B){box}
  \drawbeam(A){1}{2}
\end{pspicture}
    
\vspace{3cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,xunit=1.5,yunit=2](0,-0.3)(3,3)
  \pnode(0,2.5){A}\pnode(2,2.5){B}\pnode(2,1.5){C}
  \mirror[labelangle=-45](A)(B)(C){M}
  \optbox[position=start, labeloffset=0, labelref=relative](C)(B){box}
  \drawbeam(A){1}{2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]